# Why is forward declaration of structure not working in my code? When can it be used in C?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof, structure, forward-declaration

Isn't forward declaration, whether for structures or functions, supposed to do what forward declaration is expected to do, ie, to let us use the `structure` or `function` before they are defined? Why is the forward declaration of a structure not working in my code? And the main thing that just misses me, is forward declaration of **structures** of any use in C at all? When is it used? Can you please give me a small C program example to illustrate this?

My program gives the error `error: storage size of 'x' isn't known|`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct test;

int main(void)
{
struct test x;
printf("%zu",sizeof(x)); //Gives Error
//printf("%zu",sizeof(struct test));//This fails too
}

struct test
{
    int a;
    char b;
};
```

**New Edit** I tried to do what Carl Noum said,but even this is not working:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct test;
void foo(struct test*);

int main(void)
{
struct test x={53,'x'},*ptr=&x;
foo(ptr);
}

void foo(struct test* p)
{
    printf("%d,%c",p->a,p->b);
}

struct test
{
    int a;
    char b;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The compiler has to know the struct's layout when it compiles the main function.

A forward declaration is useful if you only have a pointer but not the actual type.

For example if you have a struct that contains a pointer to another struct

```
struct foo {
  struct bar *b;
  ...
};
```

It is also essential if the `bar` also contain `foo` like

```
struct bar;

struct foo {
  struct bar *b;
};  

struct bar {
  struct foo f;
};
```

In this case you have to have `bar` pre-declared.

A forward declaration usually means that you don't have to include `.h` file inside other `.h` file. This can speed up compilation significantly if the `.h` file is big.

Answer (score 3):

Functions yes, structures no.  `struct test` is an [incomplete type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Incomplete_types) where you use it.

A common use case for incomplete types is to declare an opaque type.  In a header file, you declare:

```
struct test;
```

And then some API that uses `struct test` only via pointers:

```
int func1(struct test *);
struct test *func2(void);
```

In the accompanying implementation, you include the full declaration so that your functions know what to do with the structure:

```
struct test
{
    int a;
    char b;
};

void func1(struct test *t)
{
    return t->a;
}
```

Edit:

Your new code doesn't do anything differently - you're still trying to operate on an incomplete type, and you still can't do that.  In particular, this declaration:

```
struct test x = {53,'x'};
```

Can't work if `struct test` is an incomplete type.  You can (generally) only use *pointers* to an incomplete type.  In this case, that might mean creating a function that allocates and returns a pointer to a new structure, rather than trying to declare and initialize one on the stack.

Comment: So `forward declaration` and `structures` don't go together in C and the statement `forward declaration of structures in C` is a misnomer?

Comment: @Jugni - edited to add an example of how incomplete types can be useful.

Comment: @CarNorum Please check my edit.I tried using structure pointers as arguments to functions as you said,but even that doesn't work.Where did I do wrong?

Comment: @Jugni - edited to update.  You still are trying to do things you can't do with an incomplete type.

Answer (score 1):

Struct type declared by a forward declaration (i.e. an *incomplete* type) can be used only in a limited number of ways. Applying `sizeof` to such a truct type is not one of them. On top of that, you can't use incomplete types in object definitions and you cannot access data fields of incomplete struct types.

In other words, `sizeof` requires a complete type. Your forward-declared struct type is not a complete type. Operator `->` also requres a complete type of the left-hand side. Object definition (like `struct test x`) also requires a complete type.

Comment: Please look into the new program I posted in my edit,based on Carl Norum's feedback.Even then,while using pointers,it doesn't work.Can you give me some working code work forward declaration works?

Comment: @Jugni: "Using pointers" doesn't change much by itself. You are not allowed to access the data fileds of incomplete struct types. You are not allowed to define objects of incomplete struct types, which is why your modified program does not compile.